# Connecting words in columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nlp

**Background**

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
#create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Before' : ['there are many different', 
                               'i like a lot of sports ', 
                               'the middle east has many '], 
                   'After' : ['in the bright blue box', 
                               'because they go really fast ', 
                               'to ride and have fun '],

                  'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                  'Word' : ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels'],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

                 })

#rearrange
df = df[['P_ID', 'N_ID', 'Before', 'Word','After']]
```

which creates the following `df`

```
  P_ID  N_ID    Before                 Words       After
0   1   A1   there are many different   crayons     in the bright blue box
1   2   A2  i like a lot of sports      cars      because they go really fast
2   3   A3  the middle east has many    camels      to ride and have fun
```

**Goals**

1) Connect the words in `Before` and `After` columns with the words in the `Word` column

2) Create a `new_column`

**Desired Output**

A  `new_column` with the following output

```
new_column
there are many different crayons in the bright blue box
i like a lot of sports cars because they go really fast
the middle east has many camels to ride and have fun
```

**Question**

How do I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add these columns:

`df['new_column'] = df['Before'] + ' ' + df['Word'] + ' ' + df['After']`

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
#create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Before' : ['there are many different', 
                               'i like a lot of sports ', 
                               'the middle east has many '], 
                   'After' : ['in the bright blue box', 
                               'because they go really fast ', 
                               'to ride and have fun '],

                  'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                  'Word' : ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels'],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

                 })

#rearrange
df = df[['P_ID', 'N_ID', 'Word', 'Before', 'After']]
df['new_column'] = df['Before'] + ' ' + df['Word'] + ' ' + df['After']
df['new_column']
```

> ```
> 0    there are many different crayons in the bright...
> 1    i like a lot of sports  cars because they go r...
> 2    the middle east has many  camels to ride and h...
> Name: new_column, dtype: object
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns as suggested above or more general solution to many similar problem which may occure is

```
df['new_column']=df.apply(lambda x: x.Before+x.Word+x.After, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use The method cat() of the .str accessor

```
df['New_column'] = df['Before'].str.cat(df[['Word','After']],sep=" ")
```

- cat() even allows you to add a separator
- Joining multiple columns is just a matter of passing either a list of series or a dataframe containing all but the first column as a parameter to str.cat() invoked on the first column (Before):

code:

```
import pandas as pd
#create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Before' : ['there are many different',
                               'i like a lot of sports ',
                               'the middle east has many '],
                   'After' : ['in the bright blue box',
                               'because they go really fast ',
                               'to ride and have fun '],

                  'P_ID': [1,2,3],
                  'Word' : ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels'],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

                 })

#rearrange
df = df[['P_ID', 'N_ID', 'Before', 'Word','After']]
print (df)
df['New_column'] = df['Before'].str.cat(df[['Word','After']],sep=" ")
print (df)
```